# How to ask for a report separated with 1 hour?

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to send an email to someone to provide me a report for a full working day, however, I want him to send the report for each hour, for example, a report from 8 till 9, from 9 till 10... so how to say this in a proper email?

> Dear X, Please send me the report of yesterday with an interval of 1 hour?

or

> Dear X, Please send me the report of yesterday but separated with 1 hour?

Is there a better rephrasing or word for that?

Comment: Please send me a report for yesterday detailing what was done each hour.

Comment: “separated” makes me think you want me to *send* reports an hour apart, because getting multiple reports at once would be stressful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want him to send you yesterday's report with "***hourly***" details for the full working day.

> Dear X,
>
> Please send me yesterday's report with ***hourly*** details for the full working day.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the report is to be "broken down by hour."

Answer (score 1):

> Dear X,
>   Please send me a report detailing **each hour** of work yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Consider separating the two parts of your request into two separate sentences.
1) Please send me a report of your activities yesterday.
2) In your report account for each hour of work.
Or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say, please send me reports in “***hourly intervals***”.